# mtime changes when trying to delete files followed by directories. Best way to delete files and directories.?

Tags: bash, shell, find, ksh

I have written the following code to delete files older than 7 days, followed by deleting empty directories older than 7 days.

## deleting files

```
find "$CDIR" ! -type d -mtime +7 -exec sh -c '

        for pathname do

            if ! rm -fv "$pathname"; then

            ((err_count_f++))

            fi

        done' sh {} +
```

## deleting directories

```
find "$CDIR" -type d -empty -mtime +7 -exec sh -c '

        for pathname do

            if ! rmdir -v "$pathname"; then 

            ((err_count_d++))

            fi

        done' sh {} +`
```

But, when I delete the files inside a dir, the mtime of the dir is changing, so concerned empty directories are not getting deleted. What is the best way to overcome this.?

Comment: Note that `-mtime +7` means older than 8 days (age rounded down to an integer number of days *stritly* greater than 7).

Comment: Related: [find: suppress "Directory not empty"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/395998)

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` (and GNU `find` or compatible for `-delete`):

```
cd -P -- "$CDIR" || exit
old_dirs=(**/*(DNm+6))
find . -mtime +6 ! -type d -delete
empty_old_dirs=($^old_dirs(N^F))
(($#empty_old_dirs == 0)) || rmdir -- $empty_old_dirs
```

Note that `-mtime` and `zsh`'s `m` glob qualifier works with ages in integer (rounded down) number of days. `-mtime -6` is for the age being strictly less than 6, `-mtime 6` is for that age being 6 (so in effect, between 6 and 7 days) and `-mtime +6` for that age *strictly* greater than 6, so 7 days and above.

So for files that are more than 7 days old, you want `-mtime +6`, not `-mtime +7` (at least with POSIX compliant `find` implementations, not all are but GNU's one is in that regard).

Answer (score 0):

You can first add the 7 day old empty directories to a temp file and run your file removal. Then search for empty directories and check against the file.

```
dirs_mtime7=$(mktemp) ## Create a temp file. 
find "$CDIR" -type d -mtime +7 >> "${dirs_mtime7}" 
## 
## File deletion find command goes HERE ...
##         
while IFS= read -r -d '' a; do         
 grep -q -F -f "${dirs_mtime7}" <<< "${a}" && rmdir -v "${a}" 
done < <(find "$CDIR" -type d -empty -print0)
```

Since they are only getting older you can just add to the temp file the new 7 day + directories. Create the dirs_mtime7 directory only once and add to it.